# Calling function inside with-statement gives error variable not found in function scope

Tags: r, scope, local-variables, with-statement, imputation

I am preparing a bootstrapped estimation of a mean prediction error on a multiple imputed dataset. My function seems to be unable to find the dependent variable in scope. Is there some way to circumvent that?

Multiple imputation runs smoothly, but the specific problem seems to be that the line

```
mod.nb.train <- with(data = data.mi.train, exp = glm.nb(f))
```

cannot find the variable `CG.tot`:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'CG.tot' not found

However, if I state the formula as a string:

```
glm.nb(formula=CG.tot~Fibrinogen)
```

it works...

## Minimal running example:

```
library(mice)
library(MASS)

#compute the mean prediction error on a dataframe with missing data
  predicterr <- function(f, data, indices){
    if(!(class(f)=="formula")){stop("'f' must be of the 'formula' type")}
    if(!(class(data)=="data.frame")){stop("'data' must be of the 'data.frame' type")}
    #recompute random sampling & multiple imputation
    data.test <- data[sample(nrow(data), 15),]
    data.train <- data[setdiff(rownames(data), rownames(data.test)),]
    data.mi.train <- mice(data.train)
    data.mi.test <- mice(data.test)
    #recompute model
    mod.nb.train <- with(data = data.mi.train, exp = glm.nb(f))
    coeffs <- summary(pool(mod.nb.train))[,"est"]
    #compute prediction error on each dataset row
    errvec <- apply(complete(data.mi.test, include = F, action = "long")[,c(names(coeffs)[-1], as.character(f)[2])],
                    1, function(x){
                      return(exp(sum(x[1:length(x)-1]*coeffs[-1], coeffs[1]))-x[length(x)])
    })
    return(mean(errvec))
  }
predicterr(CG.tot~Fibrinogen, d.mi)
```

## Dataset (a little long, but that's for the imputation...):

```
d <- structure(list(Hb = c(7.5, 12.9, 12.9, 10.2, 10.5, 11.2, 12.7, 
9.3, 11.7, 13.4, 151, 10.9, 5.9, 12.8, 10.2, 15.3, 13.8, 9.6, 
7.6, 12.2, 11.1, 13.6, 8.9, 7.2, 7.8, 8.7, 10.3, 14, 8.8, 7.5
), Hct = c(23, 39.8, 39.4, 31.6, 32.5, 34.4, 39, 28, 35.9, 41.2, 
43.8, 33.7, 18.6, 37.7, 31.7, 44, 87.3, 29.4, 23.6, 37.7, 34.3, 
39.8, 27.4, 22.6, 24.2, 29.1, 31.8, 43.1, 27.3, 23.3), EXTEM.CT = c(51L, 
60L, 45L, 115L, 55L, 48L, 49L, 106L, 56L, 68L, 61L, 53L, 69L, 
44L, 58L, 126L, 47L, 68L, 49L, 68L, 51L, 84L, 63L, 66L, 51L, 
108L, 63L, 51L, 53L, 63L), EXTEM.CFT = c(133L, 162L, 175L, 216L, 
101L, 60L, 140L, 248L, 137L, 203L, 113L, 199L, 316L, 90L, 224L, 
235L, 133L, 46L, 308L, 300L, 119L, 420L, 44L, 207L, 91L, 69L, 
96L, 130L, 153L, 99L), EXTEM.MCF = c(59L, 55L, 50L, 46L, 64L, 
72L, 52L, 46L, 50L, 50L, 60L, 40L, 40L, 56L, 46L, 47L, 52L, 67L, 
40L, 35L, 83L, 30L, 82L, 47L, 61L, 76L, 63L, 51L, 58L, 58L), 
    INTEM.CT = c(NA, 158L, 154L, 240L, 141L, 141L, 143L, 122L, 
    104L, 193L, 183L, 186L, 182L, 172L, 192L, 149L, 133L, 162L, 
    238L, 158L, 144L, 144L, 162L, 213L, 139L, 157L, 104L, 376L, 
    140L, 192L), INTEM.CFT = c(NA, 91L, 119L, 165L, 97L, 51L, 
    118L, 190L, 84L, 90L, 82L, 114L, 226L, 90L, 89L, 209L, NA, 
    64L, 203L, 222L, 64L, 104L, 43L, 170L, 66L, 50L, 61L, 332L, 
    70L, 66L), INTEM.MCF = c(NA, 57L, 48L, 48L, 74L, 70L, 49L, 
    50L, 50L, 55L, 58L, 49L, 40L, 57L, 48L, 46L, 64L, 68L, 44L, 
    39L, 64L, 54L, 80L, 51L, 64L, 78L, 68L, 54L, 62L, 61L), FIBTEM.CT = c(50L, 
    62L, 101L, 123L, 58L, 49L, 49L, 74L, 77L, 117L, 61L, 54L, 
    79L, 41L, 69L, 189L, 49L, 67L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 56L, 62L, 
    57L, 65L, 51L, 58L, 68L, 67L), FIBTEM.CFT = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 94L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 615L, NA, 56L, NA, NA, NA, 
    79L, NA, NA, 625L, NA, 75L, NA, 892L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1206L
    ), FIBTEM.MCF = c(9L, 9L, NA, 5L, 10L, 21L, 11L, 4L, 6L, 
    3L, 16L, 7L, 6L, 31L, NA, 4L, NA, 35L, 11L, 10L, 42L, NA, 
    28L, 13L, 22L, 28L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 21L), INR = c(1.14, 1, 1, 
    1.33, 1.01, 1.07, 1.06, 1.43, 1.22, 1.12, 1.18, 1.54, NA, 
    1.3, 1.13, 1.05, 1.09, 1.11, 1.49, 1.22, 1.33, 1.04, NA, 
    1.87, 1.67, 1, 1, 1.07, 1.12, 1.88), PTT = c(30, 28.4, 22.1, 
    37.8, 25.6, 28.9, 27.2, 32.7, 27.2, 28.9, 27.3, 69.9, 132, 
    31.9, 26.5, NA, 28.9, 44.3, 50.8, 36.6, NA, 23.5, 30, 70.6, 
    41.2, 30.1, 25.7, 26.7, 26, 41.9), Platelets = c(150, 193, 
    343, 138, 284, 216, 141, 291, 142, 230, 254, 126, NA, 249, 
    153, 308, 253, 66, 30, 41, 293, 208, 545, 141, 136, 256, 
    249, 305, 327, 112), Fibrinogen = c(1.3, NA, NA, 0.9, 2.1, 
    3.4, 2.3, 1.1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 0.8, NA, 2.3, 2.4, NA, 2.2, 
    7.4, 1.8, 1.7, NA, 2.6, 7.1, 0.6, 1.2, NA, 1.1, 2.5, 1.7, 
    2), CG.tot = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 11L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 0L, 12L, 11L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 21L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("Hb", "Hct", "EXTEM.CT", 
"EXTEM.CFT", "EXTEM.MCF", "INTEM.CT", "INTEM.CFT", "INTEM.MCF", 
"FIBTEM.CT", "FIBTEM.CFT", "FIBTEM.MCF", "INR", "PTT", "Platelets", 
"Fibrinogen", "CG.tot"), row.names = c(50L, 38L, 54L, 82L, 86L, 
4L, 24L, 78L, 59L, 58L, 72L, 16L, 85L, 81L, 45L, 77L, 70L, 6L, 
63L, 7L, 11L, 53L, 13L, 93L, 36L, 30L, 18L, 19L, 40L, 43L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing one parameter in `glm.nb`:

```
  mod.nb.train <- with(data = data.mi.train, exp = glm.nb(f, environment()))
```

and it works.

Comment: I suspected something along those lines, but I never knew one could explicitely pass environements around. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! The problem here was the way that glm behaves when you don't specify  `data` - from the docs: _If not found in data, the variables are taken from environment(formula)_ - so in this case it was looking in the 'outer' environment in which the formula was created.